# How to manage the same test case associated to 2 different issues on Jira XRAY

Tags: testing, jira, testcase, jira-xray

I wonder if we have a way to distinguish between the result of tests that cover 2 different use cases.

to illustrate my question:

Issue #1 - AAA

Issue #2 - BBB

Test Case #3- Can Cover both Issue#1 and Issue #2, but Issue#1 test result is passed and for the second issue it's failed. So the status of this test case (#3) it's also passed and also failed. So what is the best case to manage this situation? we want to avoid adding duplicated tests only because of this limitation.

Thanks

Comment: To better help you out, are you using Xray on Jira cloud or Xray on Jira server/datacenter?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Xray for Jira server/datacenter then there's a [setting](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Coverage+Settings#CoverageSettings-SeparationofConcerns) that can help you out.  If you have "separation of concerns" unchecked, then in the execution screen of a Test Run you can say how a given result affects the coverage of the covered requirements/stories, as detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Execute+Tests#ExecuteTests-AffectedRequirements).

If you have Xray for Jira cloud, this option is not yet available; if that's the case, then I would recommend reaching out to [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) and ask for this improvement.

Note: Usually, I would recommend to have a test just covering a requirement/user story. If you have the same test covering multiple stories it may be a sign that perhaps your stories need to be decomposed or clarified. A test should be as focused as possible so we can track its impacts and also the root-cause of a problem, if the test fails.
Xray documentation provides [some tips related to test cases authoring](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Best+practices+on+writing+great+Test+cases).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for that - we just create Test Plan for each release that contains the bug and then at the Test Coverage scope we choose the Test Plan, and not the Final Scope or other configurations.
if we have the same issue with the same Test Plan so we create a new test and it should be different steps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).